# Django QuerySet lookup returning multiple objects

Tags: python, django

I have a QS lookup which is returning multiple (duplicate) objects:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(receiver__exact=user_emp_type)) | queryset.filter(Q(sender__exact=self.request.user))
```

It returns the same amount of objects as the length of the reciever M2M field. e.g. if there are 3 receivers in the M2M `receiver` field there will be 3 duplicate objects.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I may not be following the logic here, but I think you actually want `queryset.filter(
            Q(receiver__exact=user_emp_type) | Q(sender__exact=self.request.user))`, i.e. join the Q inside the filter statement, rather than joining the result of the queryset.

Comment: No, this isn't the case but thank you for the try. I posted my solution below. Maybe you could answer the *why* portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that you want `distinct()` objects (no duplicates). The code now looks like this (Note: removed the `Q` lookups):

```
queryset = queryset.filter(receiver=user_emp_type) | queryset.filter(sender=self.request.user)
return queryset.distinct() # return distinct queryset
```

I don't know why I need to tell it that I only want `distinct()` objects if someone could chime in here.